# How to generate Reshift compatible table schema from a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, migration, amazon-redshift, ddl

I'm trying to create an automated pipeline to transfer data from a SQL Server table to my Redshift database. I need to do this for several tables, currently in SQL Server.

The process I'm doing for it is:

1. Automatically export data from the SQL Server table as a CSV (into a folder that is mapped to AWS S3 bucket) using a .bat script.
2. Write a Lambda function to watch for the file in the S3 bucket load it into the Redshift table and then remove the file from the bucket after completion.

The above will be a daily dump loading only the new records since the last dump. Now, before getting this pipeline going, I want to know:

Is it possible to automatically create the table in my Redshift database using the SQL Server table?? OR something that will generate a create table definition compatible for the Redshift table from the SQL Server table??  Since, I need to do it for multiple tables and the tables are really huge, I don't want to be manually doing `"CREATE TABLE .."` for each of them in Redshift.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the use-case for [AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html), which can do an initial migration but can also perform on-going incremental loads (but requires a DMS server to be running).

See:

- [Using a Microsoft SQL Server Database as a Source for AWS DMS - AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html)
- [Using an Amazon Redshift Database as a Target for AWS Database Migration Service - AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Redshift.html)

To create the equivalent schema in Amazon Redshift, you can use the [AWS Schema Conversion Tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Welcome.html), which will convert an existing database schema from one database engine to another

Answer (score 0):

As John mentioned, AWS Database Migration Service will be the best way to replicate a table from one source DB to other target DB.

If you are still just looking for getting equivalent redshift create table DDL you can use metadata tables to get that. I did same for Oracle to redshift and looped this for all the tables:

```
WITH COLUMN_DEFINITION AS (
SELECT
TABLE_NAME,
COLUMN_NAME,
CASE
    WHEN (DATA_TYPE= 'NUMBER' AND DATA_SCALE = 0 AND DATA_PRECISION <= 9) THEN 'INTEGER'
    WHEN (DATA_TYPE= 'NUMBER' AND DATA_SCALE = 0 AND DATA_PRECISION <= 18) THEN 'BIGINT'
    WHEN (DATA_TYPE= 'NUMBER' AND DATA_SCALE = 0 AND DATA_PRECISION >= 19) THEN 'DECIMAL(' || DATA_PRECISION || ',0)'
    WHEN (DATA_TYPE= 'NUMBER' AND DATA_SCALE > 0)  THEN 'DECIMAL(' || DATA_PRECISION || ',' || DATA_SCALE ||')'
    WHEN (DATA_TYPE= 'NUMBER' AND nvl(DATA_SCALE,0) = 0 AND nvl(DATA_PRECISION,0) = 0) THEN 'DECIMAL(38,18)'
    WHEN DATA_TYPE= 'CHAR' THEN 'VARCHAR(' || DATA_LENGTH || ')'
    WHEN DATA_TYPE= 'VARCHAR' THEN 'VARCHAR(' || DATA_LENGTH || ')'
    WHEN DATA_TYPE= 'VARCHAR2' THEN 'VARCHAR(' || DATA_LENGTH || ')'
    WHEN DATA_TYPE= 'DATE' THEN 'TIMESTAMP'
    WHEN DATA_TYPE= 'DATETIME' THEN 'TIMESTAMP'
    WHEN DATA_TYPE LIKE 'TIMESTAMP%' THEN 'TIMESTAMP'
    WHEN DATA_TYPE= 'LONG' THEN 'TEXT'
    WHEN DATA_TYPE= 'CLOB' THEN 'TEXT'
    WHEN DATA_TYPE LIKE '%RAW%' THEN 'TEXT'
    WHEN DATA_TYPE= 'NCHAR' THEN 'NCHAR(' || DATA_LENGTH || ')'
    WHEN DATA_TYPE= 'NVARCHAR' THEN 'NVARCHAR(' || DATA_LENGTH || ')'
    ELSE DATA_TYPE || '(' || DATA_LENGTH || ')'
    END AS REDSHIFT_COLUMN_DEFINITION
FROM  ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE LOWER(OWNER)= LOWER('<schma_name>') AND LOWER(TABLE_NAME) in 
LOWER('<Table name>')
ORDER BY COLUMN_ID
)
SELECT 'drop table if exists ' || LOWER(MAX(TABLE_NAME)) || ' cascade; ' 
FROM column_definition
UNION ALL
SELECT 'create table '|| LOWER(MAX(TABLE_NAME)) || ' ('  AS TEXT FROM 
COLUMN_DEFINITION
UNION ALL
SELECT  '    '|| LOWER(COLUMN_NAME) ||' '|| REDSHIFT_COLUMN_DEFINITION 
|| ', ' AS TEXT FROM COLUMN_DEFINITION
UNION ALL
SELECT '  );' AS TEXT FROM DUAL
```